# Prevent grails from fetching domain object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an image which belongs to a user

```
class Image {
  static belongsTo = [user: User]
  String name 
  String path
}
class User {
  String name
}
```

How can I get the user Id without fetching the user in the database :

```
myService.doIt(Image.get(1).user.id)
```

fetches the user (I just need the id here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the dynamic "fooId" property for a domain class property "foo":

```
myService.doIt(Image.get(1).userId)
```

Comment: Since what version of Grails is that dynamic property added?

Comment: It's very old, but under-documented.

Comment: Thanks a lot (missed that in doc)

Comment: Be careful, I got bitten by this today: if there's any chance that your User was already loaded by a previous query, userId will (always? sometimes? not sure..) be null. One solution here is to always use `userId ?: user.id`.

Comment: I'm using `userId` idea in a method in the domain class and while it is working fine when I `run-app`, I doesn't work when running unit spock unit tests (missing property error is reported). Is this expected?