# Cannot get the value of ID when using ignoreNotFound

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Given the following domain classes, it is possible to get the value of `author`'s ID from a `Book` object without fetching the related `Author` object like this: `Book.get(1).authorId` (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587629/prevent-grails-from-fetching-domain-object)).

```
class Author {
    hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
    belongsTo = [author: Author]
}
```

However, adding `books ignoreNotFound:true` to `Book` `static mapping` (to get around some legacy issues) causes `Book.get(1).authorId` to be `null`.

Is there a way to get the value of `AUTHOR_ID` column in the `BOOK` table when the related record is missing in the `AUTHOR` table?

Comment: (Untested) Instead of using `ignoreNotFound` can you try handling `ObjectNotFoundException` and extract the `authorId` from `book` if you have successfully got the book instance.

Comment: Taking out `ignoreNotFound` would mean we have to catch `ObjectNotFoundException` in a lot of places... not something we'd like to do :(

Comment: Ok. First of all. How was it legacy? if Author gets deleted then related book will also be gone as per the present mapping. What was the mapping (legacy code) before you made changes to domain class?